# Changing object_type to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am new to Pandas can you please help me to convert the object type to datetime.

before it was

```
index timestamp   
0        ISODate(2016-10-02T07:37:22.584+05:00)   
1        ISODate(2016-10-02T07:37:22.589+05:00)   
2        ISODate(2016-10-02T07:37:22.590+05:00)   
3        ISODate(2016-10-02T07:37:40.668+05:00)
```

replaced stings by below command :

```
df['timestamp'].replace(['ISODate','"'],'',regex=True,inplace = True)
```

Now the `df['timestamp']` is .

```
index    timestamp      
0        (2016-10-02T07:37:22.584+05:00)    
1        (2016-10-02T07:37:22.589+05:00)    
2        (2016-10-02T07:37:22.590+05:00)  
3        (2016-10-02T07:37:40.668+05:00)
```

Do help me with changing the object_type data to Date and time. any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str[1:-1]
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'] )
```